# Plivo get all live calls not working with jquery get request

Tags: jquery, plivo

I used this to call ajax get request

```
       // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
       // and remember the jqxhr object for this request
       var jqxhr = $.get("https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/{auth_id}/Call/?status=live", function(data) {
            console.log( "success" + data);
       })

       .done(function(data) {
           console.log( "second success" );
       })

       .fail(function(data) {
           console.log( "error" );
       })
       .always(function(data) {
           console.log( "finished" );
           console.log(data);
       });

        // Perform other work here ...

        // Set another completion function for the request above
        jqxhr.always(function() {
            alert( "second finished" );
        });
    })
```

and the response is error see here https://www.screencast.com/t/lI6UdQ5H

**note:** {auth_id} I already replace that with my auth_id provided by plivo.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seem to work. I have made a demo here. please check your ajax url.

https://jsfiddle.net/aquadk/ez8Lae5v/3/

```
  function mylogger(aValue) {
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("msg");
    theDiv.innerHTML += aValue + '<br>'
      //console.log( "second success" );
  }
  var USERNAME = 'userid';
  var PASSWORD = 'pass'
    // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
    // and remember the jqxhr object for this request
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/{auth_id}/Call/?status=live",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)
    },
    success: function() {
      mylogger("success" + data);
    }
  })

  .done(function(data) {
    mylogger("second success");
  })

  .fail(function(data) {
      mylogger("error");
    })
    .always(function(data) {
      mylogger("finished");
      mylogger(data);
    });

  // Perform other work here ...

  // Set another completion function for the request above
  jqxhr.always(function() {
    mylogger("second finished");
  });
```

html

```
<Div id="msg">

</Div>
```

Comment: Hi @Rene, Thanks for help. I tested and that should not show error message but success or something response.

Comment: Have you tried to change the url in my code with yours

Comment: Yes I tried and the response is the same with yours.

Comment: Is your account limited to a domain? can you get a response direct from a browser?

Comment: Oh I just visit this url https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/{auth_id}/Call/?status=live with my auth_id in it its shows me username and password field https://www.screencast.com/t/odBCwYLuN3 and I am able to login now using my AUTH ID as username and AUTH TOKEN as password see here https://www.screencast.com/t/rMLaqUzCa. Now my problem how I can trigger this username and password via jquery?

Comment: try changing $.get to this

`$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: ""https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/{auth_id}/Call/?status=live",
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)
  },
  success: function (){
    alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
  }
});`

Comment: I have changed my code, it should work now, with an username and password

Comment: Thanks and this should works now but I have origin issue https://www.screencast.com/t/igXM8xFp35a

Comment: Found this one.
https://brazielbraziel.blogspot.dk/2013/04/plivo-sdk-call-recording.html

Comment: But it seems, you need to create ajax call from a server.